# pop3.quit() vs pop3.close() not properly documented, what is the difference?

Tags: python

I've noticed that pop3.quit() will mark emails as "read" or "deleted" or something like that (i.e., I have one script that reads emails and runs pop3.quit() at the end of the file, and this inhibits the emails that were read during that session from being read again.)

I also have a script that runs pop3.close() and for some reason this allows the emails to be read again after the script has exited.

Where are these differences documented? In the 3.5 documentation pop3.close() isn't even documented...

I'm currently porting over the scripts into IMAP because I'm a scrub, but for the time being can anyone offer a detailed description of the differences between quit and close?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that `quit` also sends the `QUIT` command to the email server.

You can see it on the source [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aed3c541b2f1/Lib/poplib.py#l272).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/poplib.py#l272

```
def quit(self):
    """Signoff: commit changes on server, unlock mailbox, close connection."""
    resp = self._shortcmd('QUIT')
    self.close()
    return resp

def close(self):
    """Close the connection without assuming anything about it."""
    try:
        file = self.file
        self.file = None
        if file is not None:
            file.close()
    finally:
        sock = self.sock
        self.sock = None
        if sock is not None:
            try:
                sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            except OSError as e:
                # The server might already have closed the connection
                if e.errno != errno.ENOTCONN:
                    raise
            finally:
                sock.close()
```

So it sends a QUIT command, which is described in the RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt

> When the client issues the QUIT command from the TRANSACTION state,
>      the POP3 session enters the UPDATE state.
>
> The POP3 server removes all messages marked as deleted
>                from the maildrop and replies as to the status of this
>                operation.  If there is an error, such as a resource
>                shortage, encountered while removing messages, the
>                maildrop may result in having some or none of the messages
>                marked as deleted be removed.  In no case may the server
>                remove any messages not marked as deleted.